# Ubuntu 18.04 USB installer fails to start: "Ubiquity not installed"

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, ubiquity

Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on an Asus UX305C.

I Downloaded Ubuntu Desktop ISO on 21/06/2018 about 16:00H

I used Unetbootin from a ThinkPad running 18.04 to install the iso files onto a USB2 SanDisk USB.

I boot the laptop from the USB. I chose Install.

Instead of Installing it takes me to the "try Ubuntu" live session.
I click install disk icon nothing happens.

I tried to manually run Ubiquity. It produces a crash report that says Ubiquity is not installed.

I go to that location and the BIN directory is there. 
I run it again (with the bug report open) to be sure that it's currently running.

Close bug report, run again. Nothing. Wait a bit, get same bug crash report.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your ISO might be broken. Have you verified the checksum? Also I'll recommend using Etcher to burn ISO to USB

Comment: @Kulfy I always used Unetbootin with USB drive 4Go and never had a problem with it, i just hope that ArchaicLord didn't use a USB drive too small

Comment: Please see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu/152902#152902

Comment: I have fixed it. I dont' know how to mark comment as answer. 

I used a 16GB USB. 

I re-downloaded ubuntu-desktop.iso and I used etcher to flash to the drive.
Its working perfectly now.

Thank you

Comment: @cmak.fr As it turned out it's not a duplicate of that question because apparently the problem was that UNetbootin is not supported in 18.04 so the Ubuntu installer crashed, but using Etcher to flash to the USB drive worked.

Comment: @ArchaicLord just write whatever you've written in comments in answer and mark it as Accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I re-downloaded the ubuntu-desktop.iso

I then used Etcher to flash to the drive.

It's working perfectly now.